# Usefulness of Pretrained NN's for performing binary segmentation in images

Tags: deep-learning, image-segmentation, pre-trained-model, anomaly-detection, imagenet

I am trying to perform binary segmentation on a custom dataset (DAGM dataset in my case [Link to the dataset](https://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/conference/dagm/2007/prizes.html)

I was just curious to know if pretrained networks on the imagenet dataset like VGG,Resnet will be of any particular use as I am not trying to segment objects like cats,dogs etc but anomalies in the images.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would want to fine tune a model on your new dataset which was previously trained and tuned on a similar problem.  Neural networks extract features from samples and use those features to classify. If you have previously trained your network on biomedical dataset, then it has learned how to extract features from those models. So try to find a model that was trained on similar domain.

Also you can check the below link for more insight about the issue.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_interference